# Stripe Integration using Kotlin in a Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, dependencies, stripe-payments

Has anyone done Stripe Integration using Kotlin? It would be great to see some documentation about the project structure and HTTP requests!

`Main problem`: I am unable to find the gradle dependency for Kotlin. Does something like that even exist?

*Note: I am not using Kotlin for Android so please don't try to answer with this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin inter-op with Java is almost perfect. For most companies it doesn't make sense to build an *adapter* layer which *somehow* make it easier to work with their product using Kotlin. There is really no need for it.

There is no specific library for Kotlin, just keep using [Stripe-Java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java), you'll be fine.
If compatibility issues arise, you'll most likely be able to handle them by yourself, maybe by writing a (very) small portion of your codebase in Java, but that's a remote possibility.

And remember the GitHub issue tracker is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is what I tried doing initially (added a dependency: `compile "com.stripe:stripe-java:8.1.0"`) but the example given in the README file is not working.

Comment: @Raj what do you mean with "is not working"? I don't think it is related to you using Kotlin. It must be a mis-configuration. Are you receiving an exception?

Comment: Sorry! Kind of a Kotlin beginner here! `Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_...";` is `expecting member declaration`.

Comment: @Raj mmmh, could you edit the question including the problematic portion of your code? So that I can have a global vision

Comment: Oh, I was being a noobie. I fixed it! Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @Raj no problem. If you find difficulties with Kotlin, just ping me here. Btw, that statement couldn't compile, you were trying to assign something in a *declaration* block of the class.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I realized that the second I hit send! :P